# how to access model data of type list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model with an attribute of type list and a database I created with EntityFramework to create Data. I'm trying to display it in a table but having trouble accessing the elements in the list.

```
public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the controller that returns the view in which I created the table

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }
```

this is the view:

```
@model MadaEFOne.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Category</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dishes)</dt>
        <dd>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>price</th>
            </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model.Dishes.ToList())
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Name</td>
                        <td>@item.Price</td>
                    </tr>
                }

        </table>
</dd>

    </dl>
```

If I'm not wrong the error is in the foreach loop, because `Model.Dishes.ToList()` is returning null. I cant figure out what the right syntax is.
I couldn't find anything similar so any advice on where I can or why it's wrong will e highly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: i think the issue is in the EF not in the  view. have you checked `Dishes` collection in  `Details` Action?

Comment: If passing the EF Model to a view you will need to eager load the child collection (Dishes) for them to be included.  `db.Categories.Include(x => x.Dishes).Find(id);`

Comment: Hey Steve, I'm not sure I understand why I need to add that and where? anywhere I can read about it?